# std::strftime crashes with incorrect input

Tags: c++, time

This is how i am using the function to extract date and time.

```
std::strftime(&stdstrSystemTime[0], stdstrSystemTime.size(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", std::localtime(&now));
```

but if the format text is not formatted properly the application crashes like

```
std::strftime(&stdstrSystemTime[0], stdstrSystemTime.size(), "%Y-%m-%d %:%M:%S", std::localtime(&now));
```

How can i stop the application from crashing if the format text is not correct ?

Comment: Welcome to the curse of c-style format arguments. Some compilers will emit warnings if you gooned the arguments and this is far more useful than preventing a crash over bad input. If this is a compile time typo, you do not want to prevent the crash. You should be overjoyed that something in C++ loves you enough to tell you you smurfed up. If the format string is a runtime artifact, you want to fix the generator. If the format string came from outside the program, you should be testing it for validity before you even dream of using it. The forces of evil love people who don't test the inputs.

Comment: General gist: Don't try to hide the problem. Fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that you are taking format string from outwhere, maybe from user input.

So as you cannot make your strftime not crash, you have to validate format string before you call strftime.

For example, you can:

1. Use regular expressions to find all sequences like 
   "%[^aAbBcCdDeFgGhHIjmMnprRStTuUVwWxXyYzZ%]"
    (format letters are taken from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/)
2. If you've found such a substring you just don't run strftime and give your user error message like "Error! Incorrect input!" and maybe location of the error in format string.

for that you can use regex_match from std lib http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/

```cpp
#include <regex>
#include <string>
...
// defining regex pattern:
std::string pattern = "%[^aAbBcCdDeFgGhHIjmMnprRStTuUVwWxXyYzZ%]";
...
// user_format - is a variable with possible wrong date format
// if regexp didn't match then...
if (! std::regex_match (user_format, std::regex(pattern)))
{
    // run your code!
    std::strftime(&stdstrSystemTime[0], stdstrSystemTime.size(), user_format, std::localtime(&now));
}
else
{
    // lets pretend returning false means an error
    return false;
}
```

Maybe this example not covers all the cases it's just a draft. But I think you get the idea.
Also, it'll be nice to have a function like "validate_date_format" to use it everywhere in your programm with convinience